# Teiid embedded cache max entries

Tags: teiid

We are using query caching with Teiid embedded. But it is limited to 1024 resultset.
In teiid standalone we can change this property in the file standalone-teiid.xml.
But how can we change it in teiid embedded?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you initialized the embedded engine, the cache factory you set as shown at [1]. The default is defined if you not configured explicitly [2]. If you are using the Infinispan cache store then it depends on the Infinispan configuration [3].

[1]https://github.com/teiid/teiid/blob/master/runtime/src/main/java/org/teiid/runtime/EmbeddedConfiguration.java#L143

[2]https://github.com/teiid/teiid/blob/master/runtime/src/main/java/org/teiid/runtime/EmbeddedServer.java#L409

[3] https://github.com/teiid/teiid/blob/master/wildfly/cache-infinispan/src/main/resources/infinispan-config.xml